# Merge two lists of dictionaries (sub)

Tags: python

Similar questions have already been asked, but I could not find the result I'm looking for.

I have two lists of dictionaries:

```
[{'name': 'Vijver', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 0},{'name': 'Boom', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 1}]
[{'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 0, 'locked': False},{'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 1, 'locked': False}]
```

The 'id' is the same in both dictionaries. I'm not sure if the lists are ordered.

I would like to merge them with the following result:

```
[{'name': 'Vijver', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 0, 'status': {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 0, 'locked': False}},{'name': 'Boom', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 1, 'status': {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 1, 'locked': False}}]
```

How can this be done in Python (3.9+)? Pandas is too heavy, preferably something more light.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite simple, you just need to iterate through the two lists and add a key to the dictionary with the value of the 'inner' dictionary.

```py
list_dict = [
    {'name': 'Vijver', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 0},
    {'name': 'Boom', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 1}
]

status_list = [
    {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 0, 'locked': False},
    {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 1, 'locked': False}
]

for idx in range(len(list_dict)):
    list_dict[idx]["status"] = status_list[idx]

desired_dict_list = [
    {
        'name': 'Vijver',
        'room': 255,
        'module_type': 'O',
        'id': 0,
        'status': {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 0, 'locked': False}
    },
    {
        'name': 'Boom',
        'room': 255,
        'module_type': 'O',
        'id': 1,
        'status': {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 1, 'locked': False}
    }
]

for idx in range(len(desired_dict_list)):
    if list_dict[idx] != desired_dict_list[idx]:
        raise ValueError("Not valid dictionary!")

print(f"Valid dictionary: {list_dict}")
```

Output:

```sh
Valid dictionary: [{'name': 'Vijver', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 0, 'status': {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 0, 'locked': False}}, {'name': 'Boom', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 1, 'status': {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 1, 'locked': False}}]
```

You only need the code till the first for-loop, the code after the definition of `desired_dict_list` is just to validate the concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension in order to produce for each list a dictionary that maps `id`s to corresponding entries, and then use those dictionaries to combine them.

For instance:

```
l = [{'name': 'Vijver', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 0},{'name': 'Boom', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 1}]
d = {elem["id"] : elem for elem in l}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using python 3.9+ you can use `|` to merge dictionaries:

```
l1 = [{'name': 'Vijver', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 0}, {'name': 'Boom', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 1}]
print(f'{l1 = }')
l2 = [{'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 0, 'locked': False}, {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 1, 'locked': False}]
print(f'{l2 = }')
l3 = [d1 | {'status': d2} for d1, d2 in zip(l1, l2)]
print(f'{l3 = }')
expected = [{'name': 'Vijver', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 0, 'status': {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 0, 'locked': False}}, {'name': 'Boom', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 1, 'status': {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 1, 'locked': False}}]
print(f'{expected = }')
print(f'{expected == l3 = }')
```

**Output:**

```
l1 = [{'name': 'Vijver', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 0}, {'name': 'Boom', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 1}]
l2 = [{'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 0, 'locked': False}, {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 1, 'locked': False}]
l3 = [{'name': 'Vijver', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 0, 'status': {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 0, 'locked': False}}, {'name': 'Boom', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 1, 'status': {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 1, 'locked': False}}]
expected = [{'name': 'Vijver', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 0, 'status': {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 0, 'locked': False}}, {'name': 'Boom', 'room': 255, 'module_type': 'O', 'id': 1, 'status': {'status': 0, 'dimmer': 100, 'ctimer': 0, 'id': 1, 'locked': False}}]
expected == l3 = True
```